# SumAsync of nullable column with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

One of the column in my table is a nullable integer. I chose this type to differentiate between a known value of `0` and an unknown value, which is saved as `NULL`. Now, I'd like to use EF Core to calculate sum of these values while respecting this semantics - i.e. if one of the values is not known (is `NULL`), the whole sum is not known (is `NULL`).

The problem is that EF Core's [SumAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.sumasync?view=efcore-5.0) generates SQL command which transforms `NULL` into 0. For example, this EF Core query:

```cs
string[] codes = new[] { "CODE1", "CODE2" };
int? totalWeight = await ctx.Skus.Where(s => codes.Contains(s.Code)).SumAsync(s => s.WeightG);
```

Generates the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(s."WeightG"), 0)::INT -- column WeightG is nullable
FROM "Skus" AS s
WHERE s."Code" = ANY (@__codes_0)
```

Which means that I can't differentiate between known SUM of `0`, and and unknown total sum. How can I modify the EF Core query to preserve these semantics - to have the database return  `NULL` when there is a `NULL` value in the list of values that's being `SUM`med?

Comment: When should the sum be `null`? When all comprising weights are `null`, or just one?

Comment: @GertArnold just one